# Calculate golden ratio

Tags: code-golf, math, kolmogorov-complexity

Write the shortest code, in number of bytes, to display, return, or evaluate to the golden ratio (that is, the positive root of the quadratic equation: \$x^2-x-1=0\$, approximately
1.618033988749895), to at least 15 significant figures. No input will be given to your program.

Sample in Stutsk programming language:

```
1 100 { 1 + 1 swp / } repeat print
```

Comment: This question will need a scoring criteria, input/output specification, etc. Please read the FAQ - http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @ardnew: I'll try to at least nail down an input (namely none) and winning criterion (shortest code). The expected output is, well...most languages support double-precision, so let's do that and call it good. :-)

Answer (score 19):

### Perl, Python - 10 chars

probably other languages too

```
.5+5**.5/2
```

Comment: That's also a nice entry for the polyglot challenge :) (http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6764/3527)

Comment: `.5+5^.5/2` will work in Octave/MATLAB, probably some others too

Answer (score 10):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), 2 bytes

```julia
φ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/@9QUJSZV5KmoaSqZ2iapqTz/3zbf83/AA)

I'm surprised nobody has posted this yet...

Comment: That’s an old version of Julia! Does it not work in 1.5?

Comment: Julia 1.0+ moved a lot of stuff out of Base, often making the code much more verbose...

Comment: Why it's 2 bytes? I just see one character, does the `tab` include in length of program?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi Unlike golfing languages, Julia doesn't use a custom codepage, so this is scored in UTF-8, where greek letters use 2 bytes.

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica 11

```
GoldenRatio
```

This is the irrational number itself, not an approximation of it.

**Examples** (first 2 examples from Mathematica documentation)

```
FullSimplify[GoldenRatio^4 - GoldenRatio]
FullSimplify[GoldenRatio^20 + 1/GoldenRatio^20]
FullSimplify[GoldenRatio^2 - GoldenRatio - 1]
```

> 3 + Sqrt[5]
>
> 15127
>
> 0

Answer (score 8):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 8 bytes

```
aa-a~1
a
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fpodwh2z33)

Comment: Wait yo using regressions to get constants is actually so smart, you should post that as a tip on the [Desmos code golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230100/tips-for-code-golfing-in-desmos) page. I've always done it like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xlrnlf4yaf), which is 11 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

**PHP 17 chars**

This one is just trolling, but hey.

```
1.618033988749895
```

Answer (score 6):

## k (10 chars)

As continued fraction:

```
{%x%x+1}/1
```

Or in closed form for 11:

```
%2%1+sqrt 5
```

Answer (score 6):

## J, 7 chars

```
-:1+%:5
```

some more text for the filter (my first J solution, heh)

Comment: When I run `-:1+%:5`, the result is `1.61803`. Is something more needed in the program (or system settings) to get the required "at least 15 significant figures"?

Comment: @r.e.s the question asks " to display, return, or evaluate". It is evaluated to the correct precision, just not displayed. It's a compliant answer.

Answer (score 6):

## APL, 7

```
2÷⍨1+√5
÷2÷1+√5
.5×1+√5
.5+√5÷4
```

Curses! I can't find a way to do it in less than 7 characters! Dialect is Nars2000.

Comment: Dyalog APL: `1+∘÷⍣=1`

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ECMAScript), 10 chars

```
5**.5/2+.5
```

This is the same as the Perl & Python submission - thanks to **Redwolf Programs** for telling me about this.

However, back in 2012, when this answer was originally written, the `**` operator did not exist in JavaScript. While almost all browsers and do now support the exponentiation operator, according to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_exponentiation), as of July 2020, around 9% of users still does not support it, including the latest version of Internet Explorer. Thus, the old version of the answer:

**JavaScript (backwards-compatible), 17 chars**

```
Math.sqrt(5)/2+.5
```

Comment: There's now a `**` operator, so `5**.5/2+.5` would work too. Note that this is the same as the python submission.

Answer (score 3):

## Language Agnostic, 15 chars

```
9227465/5702887
```

If all you need is enough precision for an IEEE 32 bit float, you can do it in 9 chars:

```
6765/4181
```

This will only work for languages that don't treat integer division specially.

Comment: `9227465/5702887` produces only 13 correct digits - it differs on 14. digit.

Comment: `14930352/9227465` is probably the shortest, you can [find it using optimal algorithm](http://www.mindspring.com/~alanh/fracs.html) as [advised on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/247960/15731)

Answer (score 3):

## dc, 8 chars

```
Fk5v1+2/
```

The value is on top of the stack - can be printed by adding `p` to the end of the program.
`F` pushes 15 on the stack ([trick found here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/17050/2800)), `k` sets the precision to 15 digits. The rest is normal postfix notation :-) `v` is a square root. Trailing `p` for print was omitted.

Comment: [It can be argued](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6827/3440) that the `p` is not needed, because the requirement is to *evaluate* (not necessarily display) to 15 places.

Comment: @r.e.s. interesting bending of rules :) thanks, updated :)

Answer (score 3):

**J, <strike>10</strike> <strike>9</strike> 8 chars**

```
p.1,1,_1
```

(root of polynomial: -x^2+x+1)

```
>:@%^:_+1
```

(continued fraction (9 chars))

```
%:@>:^:_+1
```

(continued root: (10 chars))

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
5X‚t;O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fNOJRw6wSa////wE)

## Explanation

```
5      Push 5
 X     Push 1
  ‚    Pair: [5, 1]
   t   Square root: [2.23606797749979, 1.0]
    ;  Halve: [1.118033988749895, 0.5]
     O Sum: 1.618033988749895
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), 3 bytes

```
phi
```

Just a builtin, too short to be compressed. Returns `1.61803398874989484820458683436563811`.

A more interesting one. If running in the downloadable version, this will print `n` digits, given the command:

```sh
arn run file.arn -p n
```

or 25 digits if the `-p` flag is not provided.

If running in the online version, this will print the first 50 digits.

### [6 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
l[├Qn0
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=Oi0xKzovNQ==&input=)

#### Explanation

Unpacked: `:-1+:/5`

```
:-       Halve
    1    Literal one
  +      Plus
    :/   Square root of
      5  Literal five
```

Comment: arn has no increment command?

Comment: The increment command is two bytes, `++`. This increments variables too, which gives it a unique purpose.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

**(floating-point; accurate to 15 significant figures)**

```
½→√5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DeR22THnXMMv3/HwA)

This seems (to me) to be surprisingly readable for a golfing language...

```
  √5    # square root of 5
 →      # increment 
½       # halve
```

---

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

**(calculation as arbitrary precision rational number)**

```
!Ẋ/İf!5İ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fqaVoaGBgcGTDo8YNj5oa/ys@3NWlf2RDmqIpWOj/fwA) (TIO header converts the rational number [expressed in [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) as a fraction] to its first 1000 decimal digits)

```
  /         # get the ratio of 
 Ẋ          # every pair of elements of
   İf       # the fibonacci sequence;
!           # now select the ratio at position
     !5İ⁰   # 10^5 (change to !9İ⁰ for more accuracy with same byte-count)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 102 bytes

```
(C%;_#!7[}{3Wyw/St,+0/(-&Jlk"FEg|{A?~,`<^:r[Y64m3kT0Rg,xwc;J`&%#5"!~Bji.-,X;POsMppn"2GFEiCg+e?>b<;_#![
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/1/DWdU6XlnRPLq22ji8slw/uERH20BfQ1fNKydbyc01vaba0b5OJ8EmzqooOtLMJNc4O8QgKF2nojzZ2itBTVXZVEmxzikrU09XJ8I6wL/Yt6AgT8nI3c010zldO9XeLskGZHr0//8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainf](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 93 bytes

```
+++++++[>+++++++<-]>.---.++++++++.-----.+++++++.--------.+++..++++++.-..-.---.+++++.-.+.----.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwKi7aAMG91YOz1dXV09KF8bxEFwITyogJ4eTFAPiOCqgGyIOr3//wE)

It works :/
Not very optimised though. I can’t think of any way to optimize this, although I’m sure a way exists.

Explanation:

```
+++++++         Add seven to cell at 0.
[               Begin a loop.
     >+++++++   Add seven to cell at 1.
     <          Go back to cell 0.
     -          Decrement the counter there (soon it will reach 0).
]               End loop when cell 0 reaches 0 after 7 repetitions.
>               Go to cell 1 which is now 49.
.               Print it (1).
---.            Decrement 3 to get 46 (period) then print it.

Afterwards, not much explanation is needed. Just add some 
or subtract some and repeat until everything is printed.
++++++++.-----.+++++++.--------.+++..++++++.-..-.---.+++++.-.+.----.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 8 bytes

```
(1+1%)/1
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxlzMEOgjAMgOF7n4KLicaw2qCw8TZN6cA4N3Ql8eSzy93z/+WP45HOdDghAcTm25DryV+6Lng/XIMPNwCExWytI6KUSeeSoqvG8tCPLJxndVKe+Nq02r3kiv3gCYWTbIlN291Pmts37xXgb/8DC40lmw==)

Adapted from the [built-in docs](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k/src/commit/875e1d94e181ea59f63cedc366095bc40fb507a7/repl.k#L180).

- `(...)/1` set up a converge-reduce, seeded with 1 and run until two successive iterations return the same result

  - `(1+1%)` add one to the inverse of the current value, and feed that into the next iteration

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby - 14 chars

```
(­5**0.5)/2+0.5
```

Based on the <strike>Javascript</strike> Perl answer above.

Comment: Better base it on the Perl answer instead, `5**0.5` is shorter than `Math.sqrt(­5)`.

Comment: My mind was skipping on me, as I could not recall what the exponential equivalent to `sqrt` was....

Comment: 8 years late... the parentheses are not needed.

Answer (score 2):

## Almost language agnostic, 9 chars

#### (tested in R):

```
.5+5^.5/2
```

In R, evaluates full double precision. More digits can be seen by setting `options(digits=99)`. The question says "evaluate", so that goes with the rules.

Comment: **Excel, 10 chars** just prepend an `=` sign before this.

Answer (score 2):

## x86 machine code, 13 bytes

Hexdump:

```
b1 7f d9 e8 d9 e8 de c1 d9 fa e2 f8 c3
```

Disassembly:

```
100139D0 B1 7F                mov         cl,7Fh  
100139D2 D9 E8                fld1  
    again:
100139D4 D9 E8                fld1  
100139D6 DE C1                faddp       st(1),st  
100139D8 D9 FA                fsqrt  
100139DA E2 F8                loop        again (100139D4h)  
100139DC C3                   ret
```

Uses the converging sequence `an = sqrt(an-1 + 1)`.

The number of iterations is determined by the contents of `ecx`, which is mostly garbage. The minimal number of iterations is 127, which guarantees good precision (actually, 30 iterations should be enough). In the worst case, the calculation will take a few minutes (2<sup>32</sup>-1 iterations), and in the best case, it's instantaneous (127 iterations).

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 11 bytes

```
(1+5**.5)/2
```

= 1.618033988749895

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

## Whispers v3, 16 bytes

```
> φ
>> Output 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTuF8G5ednYJ/aUlBaYmC4f//AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>29</s>, 25 bytes

Saved **4 bytes**!

After posting this answer I noticed the example Stutsk program and realized that I could probably save a few bytes. My new answer is based off the example given in the question. This program works because the golden ration can be expressed as a [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Alternative_forms).

`golden_ratio = 1+1/(1+1/(1+1/...))`

```
ff*101.;n~<
$1$,1+$:?!^1-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/Py1Ny9DAUM86r86GS8VQRcdQW8XKXjHOUPf/fwA)

### Old Answer

```
f201.;n,2+1~<
$:5$,+2,$:?!^1-
```

The second line approximates the sqrt of 5. After looping 15 times, this value is used to calculate the golden ratio.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P83IwFDPOk/HSNuwzoZLxcpURUfbSEfFyl4xzlD3/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
.n3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy/P@P9/AA)

11 bytes without builtin:

```
+c@5 2 2 .5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XzvZwVTBCAj1TP//BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## dc - 11 chars

```
15k5v2/.5+p
```

The most character-consuming task is setting the decimal precision..

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica - 31

```
N[x/.Solve[x^2-x-1==0][[2]],16]

1.618033988749895
```

(It's going to be the longest code, I expect...:)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
MQ
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=TVE)

Or 6 bytes without the built-in:

```
½+5¬/2
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=vSs1rC8y)

Comment: `# ` (commonmark migration)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 1 [byte](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
φ
```

Builtins ftw ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//982///AA)

**Without builtins it's 6 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py):**

```
51α√½Σ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/U8NzGRx2zDu09t/j/fwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
φ       # Push golden ratio builtin 1.618033988749895
        # (output the entire stack joined together implicitly as result)

5       # Push 5
 1      # Push 1
  α     # Wrap the last two values into a list: [5,1]
   √    # Take the square-root of each value: [2.23606797749979,1.0]
    ½   # Halve each: [1.118033988749895,0.5]
     Σ  # And sum this list: 1.618033988749895
        # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CJam), 7 bytes

```
X5mq+2/
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/P8I0t1DbSP//fwA)

Just one more byte than 05AB1E! Pretty simple stack-based translation of the equation on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio):

```
X5         Push 1 and 5 on to the stack
  mq       Square root the top number
    +      Add the top two numbers on the stack
     2/    Divide by two
           (implicit) output the stack
```

Comment: I've removed the non-competing tag as that [no longer exists](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges), but otherwise, nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [tips for golfing in CJam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39731/tips-for-golfing-in-cjam) as well, and hope you enjoy it here!

Comment: @caird Thanks! I've read old Code Golf threads for a while and I've seen that a few times, so I figured it was required. Thanks for the tips, I'm glad to finally try participating!

Answer (score 1):

## MUMPS, 11 bytes

```
w 5**.5+1/2
```

Output: `1.618033988749894849`

This highlights a quick about MUMPS: order of operations is evaluated left to right. Something like `.5+5**.5/2` would give us `(5.5**.5)/2` (`1.172603939955857389`).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
5t>;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/ftMTO@v9/AA)

```
5t>;  # full program
   ;  # divide...
 t    # square root of...
5     # literal...
  >   # plus 1...
   ;  # by 2
      # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 4 bytes

```
S1n;
```

This answer feels like cheating because `S1` simply pushes the golden ratio onto the stack.

This answer doesn't work with TIO, but it does work with this interpreter: [Try it online!](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/?code=%20S1n%3B&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 23 bytes

```
puts [expr (1+5**.5)/2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCE6taKgSEHDUNtUS0vPVFPfKPb/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 6 bytes

```
URT5/2
```

[Replit!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Or, here's a 7-byte equivalent in Pip Classic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fWzsoxFTf6P9/AA)

#### Explanation

```
 RT5    Square root of 5
U       Increment
    /2  Divide by 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 4 bytes

```
φ .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeal5mcn5KqUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeiYP3/fJuC3v//AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 8 bytes

```
=5e.5+/p
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%3D5e.5%2B%2Fp&inputs=)

## Explanation

```
=5          set top of stack to 5
  e.5       square root
     +      increment
      /     divide by 2
       p    print value
```

This first approach is pretty boring, it's just a direct calculation. Here's a slightly more exciting 13-byte method which calculates many Fibonacci numbers then finds the ratio between them:

```
+s[+~$]99$/~p
```

[Try it Online!](https://rattleinterpreter.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&code=%2Bs%5B%2B%7E%24%5D99%24%2F%7Ep&inputs=)

## Explanation

```
+s              increment the top of the stack (to 1) and save to memory
  [   ]99       loop 99 times
   +~           increment top of stack by the value in memory
     $          swap the top of the stack for the value in memory
         $      swap the top of the stack for the value in memory
          /~    divide the top of the stack by the value in memory
            p   print value
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ḋ`, 2 bytes

```
kg
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCJrZyIsIiIsIiJd)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 33 bytes

```
ratio=(1+5**(1/2))/2
print(ratio)
```

Output:

```
1.618033988749895
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! You should indicate in your answer which language this is, as well as the byte count. Furthermore, I've edited your answer slightly to improve the formatting. Could you also edit in a link to a site where users can test your code, such as [Try It Online!](https://tio.run)? Hope you enjoy it here at CGCC!

Comment: `(1+5**(1/2))/2` is by itself is a snippet so wouldn't be a valid answer, and `ratio=(1+5**(1/2))/2<newline>print(ratio)` is sufficiently long it may not be a serious contender for the winning criteria of the challenge.

Comment: [22 bytes, making it a serious submission](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8NQ21RLS8NQ30hTE4gV/v8HAA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Lyxal [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8NQ21RLS89UU99IU@H/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 37 bytes

Very basic solution, calculates exact value & prints.

```c
main(){printf("%.15f",.5+sqrt(5)/2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0lVz9A0TUlHz1S7uLCoRMNUU99I07r2/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Øp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjIL//wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [POSIX bc](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html), 13+2(?)=15(?) bytes

bc forbids non-integer exponents, so:

```python
.5+sqrt(5/4)
```

(incl. the newline) *plus* `-l` for the math library (which also conveniently bumps the scale); therefore:

```sh
$ echo '.5+sqrt(5)/2' | bc -l
1.61803398874989484820
```